# connection via wss with grails 3

Tags: wss, grails3

In my grails application I'm searching for a way to build a connection via wss. For connections via http or https i use the http builder. But I couldn't find out if the http builder can build connections via wss aswell. And I couldnt't find a working plugin for wss. Does anyone know a working plugin?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found no working grails plugin for wss but there is at least one good java plugin available. this worked for me: https://github.com/TakahikoKawasaki/nv-websocket-client